# Get the array file names order by name files c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(mypath);//Assuming Test is your Folder
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg"); //Getting Text files
```

How the files array could be order by name?

let's say

```
files[0].Name is 'hi1.jpg'
files[1].Name is 'hi2.jpg'
```

and so on

Answer (score 3):

It is just a call to [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) in Linq namespace

```
using System.Linq;

....
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg").OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

By the way, I suggest you to use EnumerateFiles instead of GetFiles. In particular if you have to loop over the result like this

```
foreach(FileInfo fi in d.EnumerateFiles("*.jpg").OrderBy(x => x.Name))
    Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
```

As explained in the MSDN documentation

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows:  When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of
>   FileInfo objects before the whole collection is returned.  When you
>   use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of FileInfo objects to
>   be returned before you can access the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg").OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq

```
d.GetFiles("*.jpg").OrderBy(file=> file.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg").OrderBy(file => file.Name).ToArray();

- As answered above .ToArray() function along with OrderBy(columnName) does the job.